# Parse XML : retrieve value of a node where @name=RelativePath

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath, xml-parsing, xquery

Here an extract of my XML:

```
declare @FundXML XML
set @XML='<Transaction>
            <TransactionID>58265226</TransactionID>
            <SettlementCurrency>USD</SettlementCurrency>
            <SettlementAmount>
              <Amount ccy="EUR" isFundCcy="true">-1603375.03</Amount>
              <Amount ccy="USD">-1890218.82</Amount>
            </SettlementAmount>
          </Transaction>'
```

I would like to retrieve the value of tag Amount where the ccy="Tag SettlementCurrency"

If I hard-cood "USD" then it's giving me the right value :

```
select trx.col.value('./SettlementCurrency[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') Settccy,
trx.col.value('(./SettlementAmount[1]/Amount[@ccy="USD"])[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') AmountInccy 
from @xml.nodes('/Transaction') Trx(col)
```

However I would like to code something like

```
select trx.col.value('./SettlementCurrency[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') Settccy, 
trx.col.value('(./SettlementAmount[1]/Amount[@ccy=./SettlementCurrency[1]])[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') AmountInccy
from @Fundxml.nodes('/Transaction') Trx(col)
```

Could you help me writing a relative path ?
I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this

```
select trx.col.value('(SettlementCurrency/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') Settccy, 
trx.col.value('(SettlementAmount/Amount[@ccy=../../SettlementCurrency/text()])[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') AmountInccy
from @Fundxml.nodes('/Transaction') Trx(col)
```

Within the predicate you are deeper within your XML and you must jump out of `<Amount>` and out of `<SettlementAmount>` before you can dive into `<SettlementCurrency>`.

If there is only one `<SettlementCurrency>` all over your XML you might use the **deep search** (with `//`) instead:

```
select trx.col.value('(SettlementCurrency/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') Settccy, 
trx.col.value('(SettlementAmount/Amount[@ccy=//SettlementCurrency/text()])[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') AmountInccy
from @Fundxml.nodes('/Transaction') Trx(col)
```

The third option was to use `XQuery`s `let` to create a variable with this value in the context of the `</Transaction>` node:

```
select trx.col.value('(SettlementCurrency/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') Settccy, 
trx.col.value('let $c:=(SettlementCurrency/text())[1] 
               return (SettlementAmount/Amount[@ccy=$c])[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') AmountInccy
from @Fundxml.nodes('/Transaction') Trx(col)
```